# Why does Git’s single-key setting not work?

Tags: git

I’m using Git 2.7.4. I have the following snippet in my `~/.config/git/config` file:

```
[interactive]
    singleKey = true
```

However, when I run `git add -p` I still have to press enter after having made a choice for a hunk. What could be the cause for this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to `git-config` [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-interactivesingleKey) `interactive.singleKey` option requires the Perl module `Term::ReadKey` installed to work properly. Please check if this module is installed on your system and if not, install it using apropriate command. E.g. on linux systems, it would be:

```
sudo cpan Term::ReadKey
```